# Create element-wise product of matrix columns

Tags: r, matrix, vector, multiplication

```
x1  x2  x3  x11 x12 x13 x22 x23 x33
1   5   9   1   5   9   25  45  81
2   6   10  4   12  20  36  60  100
3   7   11  9   21  33  49  77  121
4   8   12  16  32  48  64  96  144
```

When `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` are given, I would like to create a matrix or data frame `x11, x12, x13, x22, x23`, and `x33` which are element-wise product of vectors `x1, x2`, and `x3`.

Actually I would like to to this for more vectors (e.g. `x1 ~ x6`) to high order (3rd or 4th).
Is there an R command which can do this?

Comment: `m[, t(col(m))[lower.tri(t(col(m)), diag=TRUE)]] * m[, rep(1:ncol(m), ncol(m):1)]` (im sure the first part of the multiplication can be simplified)

Comment: @user2957945 This is inspired by my answer which was already posted. Even `m[, rep(1:ncol(m), ncol(m):1)]` is exactly the same. If you have something new, then go ahead!

Comment: @989 ; actually it wasnt. It was an attempt to do it without using a loop (ie generate the sequence c(1,2,3,2,3,3). but more generally, it is okay to build on other answers if they can be improved - it is not a competition. (if i was interested in points i would of put it in the answer section)

Comment: @user2957945 I think other users will see the point clearly. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

We can do the combination with `expand.grid` to find all the combination of columns 1:3, then loop through the rows, subset the dataset and get the `*` of those

```
nm1 <- names(df1)[1:3]
apply(expand.grid(nm1, nm1), 1, FUN = function(x) Reduce(`*`, df1[x]))
```

The above output gives all the combinations, but suppose if we want to remove the combinations that are mirror image

```
#expand the names to two columns with each combination
d1 <- expand.grid(nm1, nm1)
#remove the rows that are duplicates
d2 <- d1[!duplicated(t(apply(d1, 1, sort))),]
#apply the function and change the column names
d3 <- apply(d2, 1, FUN = function(x) Reduce(`*`, df1[x]))
colnames(d3) <- do.call(paste0, d2)
```

and if needed `cbind` with the first 3 columns

```
cbind(df1[1:3], d3)
```

---

Another option is `combn`

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(combn(nm1, 2, FUN = function(x) Reduce(`*`, df1[x])))
nm2 <- combn(nm1, 2, FUN = paste, collapse="")
names(d1) <- nm2
d2 <- setNames(as.data.frame(df1[1:3]^2), paste0(nm1, nm1))
cbind(df1[1:3], d1, d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this quite vectorized in base R:

```
# Data
m <- matrix(1:12,4,3)

cl <- ncol(m)
res <- cbind(m, m[,rep(seq(cl), cl:1)] * m[,unlist(Map(":", 1:cl, rep(cl,cl)))])

      # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    1    5    9    1    5    9   25   45   81
# [2,]    2    6   10    4   12   20   36   60  100
# [3,]    3    7   11    9   21   33   49   77  121
# [4,]    4    8   12   16   32   48   64   96  144
```

Basically you first select the columns for which you want to have the product and then do them all at once.